# How do i ordanate a column without ordanating a line?

Tags: bash, shell

can someone explain me how do i do this?
I have a file that has three columns, and a lot of lines, and i want that the second column to be sorted in ascending order (it contains only numbers).

```
sample file; 

7.31937  736    /tmp/ref13
7.3223   5373   /tmp/ref13
7.32816  768    /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5370   /tmp/ref10
```

I want to;

```
7.31937  736    /tmp/ref13
7.3223   768    /tmp/ref13
7.32816  5370   /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5373   /tmp/ref10
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Its good to show this effort as you will get more help. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this ;

```
paste -d' '  <(awk '{print $1}' yourFile) <(awk '{print $2}' yourFile | sort -n) <(awk '{print $3}' yourFile)
```

or

```
awk '{print $2}' yourFile | sort -n | paste yourFile - | awk '{print $1"\t"$4"\t"$3}'
```

Eg:

```
user@host:/tmp$ cat t1
7.31937  736    /tmp/ref13
7.3223   5373   /tmp/ref13
7.32816  768    /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5370   /tmp/ref10

user@host:/tmp$ paste -d' '  <(awk '{print $1}' t1) <(awk '{print $2}' t1 | sort -n) <(awk '{print $3}' t1)  | column -t
7.31937  736   /tmp/ref13
7.3223   768   /tmp/ref13
7.32816  5370  /tmp/ref13
7.32955  5373  /tmp/ref10
```

Comment: could you update question in  sample file as  "7.31937 736 /tmp/ref13"

Comment: @miloski; I updated ans. Could you try this;